# Bootstrap select :visited colour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, hyperlink, visited

I use Twitter Bootstrap and I have a dropdown  formatted with Bootstrap.

I would like to color the links already visited. (with :visited)

```
<select style="max-width:250px;" class="form-control" name="esid" size="1">
   <optgroup label="Saison 1">
     <option class="Lien_liste" value="S1-E1">Episode N°1 [FR]</option>
     <option class="Lien_liste" value="S1-E2">Episode N°2 [FR]</option>
     <option class="Lien_liste" value="S1-E3">Episode N°3 [FR]</option>
   </optgroup>          
</select>
```

Thx

Comment: just drop the HTML code of your 'combo'. Because your question is ununderstandable.

Comment: Its a dropdown not a kind of condo

Comment: :visited is only available for <a> tag not for option.

Comment: how can make available for option ? with JS ?

Comment: options are not link !
You can't click on option, you can only choose it.

Comment: is there a way to mark already visited option?

Comment: nop. You can add a class for those 'visited' option , but you have to do it manually, so i won't sugges it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :visited selector is used to select visited links.

Tip: Use the :link selector to style links to unvisited pages, the :hover selector to style links when you mouse over them, and the :active selector to style links when you click on them.

Browsers limits the styles that can be set for a:visited links, due to security issues.

Allowed styles are:

```
color
background-color
border-color (and border-color for seperate sides)
outline color
column-rule-color
the color parts of fill and stroke
```

All other styles are inherited from a:link.